# Hide or show table rows on button click

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table

Is there a way to hide or show specific table rows when a button is clicked?

If I have

```
 <tr id = "x"> <td> bla bla bla</td></tr>
```

and something of the sort on the button click>

```
  protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    x.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: I assume you want to have the button post back?  If you don't want a postback, then you need a client-side, javascript solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only put in the `tr` `runat="server"`

```
<tr id = "x" runat="server"> <td> bla bla bla</td></tr>
```

With that you can see and set something at the code behind.

Another way is using `Jquery` and `toggle` action see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kjB6/) example.

Answer (score 2):

Add `runat="server"`  to your tr tag